# Can we obtain probability distribution of a repeatable event using Neural Networks?

Tags: probability, distributions, neural-networks

We have a data where input of every sample corresponds to how many times a dice is rolled. The output is the sum of all the outcomes.

For instance the data is `{{1,2},{1,5},...{4,20},{4,18}...}` where the `{4,18}` pair means that a dice was rolled 4 times and sum of 4 outcome is 18.

Supplying this data, how can we obtain a probability distribution from a Neural Network? And do we have to implement `SoftMax` function for output layer or is it just a convention?